# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt.yaml'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, yolo, yolov7

```
File "/yolov7/train.py", line 581, in <module>
    with open(Path(ckpt).parent.parent / 'opt.yaml') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt.yaml'`
```

I use `yolov7`. I have trained am model from scratch so I want to resume my training from checkpoint and my code is like this:

```
!python3 /yolov7/train.py --workers 8 --device 0 --batch-size 32 --data /yolov7/data/uav.yaml --img 480 480 --cfg /yolov7/cfg/training/yolov7-tiny.yaml --weights '/content/last.pt' --name yolov7_tiny_exp6 --hyp /yolov7/data/hyp.scratch.tiny.yaml --project /content/drive/MyDrive/YoloV4/Models/yolov7-exp6/ --epoch 201 --resume
```

When I run this on Colab nothing happens, Colab is just waiting. If you know why please let me know :)

I want to resume my training.

Comment: The error clearly states that there is a missing file. And it's in the root directory with the name `opt.yaml`. Did you check the both System and Project's root directories?

Comment: Actually this error apperaed when i try to run" python train.py --resume " code so it's not my original code's error